# SPARQL query in python - invalid replace string due to escapes not working

Tags: python, sparql

I am trying to run a SPARQL query in Python, however, when trying to use bind & replace, escaping the " is not working resulting in an error.

[image: The problem]

I tried to find some info on unicoding, but seem to find it hard to include it within this query.

Does anyone have a solution for the problem?

TEXT:

```
from rdflib import Graph
from rdflib.namespace import RDF, SKOS

g = Graph()
g.parse('\Python\Molenakker.orox.ttl')

len(g)

print(len(g))

gmls = g.query(''' 
PREFIX gwsw: <http://data.gwsw.nl/1.5/totaal/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX sparql: <http://sparql.gwsw.nl/bim/juinen#>

SELECT ?XYZ
WHERE {
    { 
    ?uri rdf:type gwsw:GemengdRiool;
         gwsw:hasAspect ?ori.
    ?ori gwsw:hasAspect ?lijn.
    ?lijn gwsw:hasValue ?GML.
    BIND(REPLACE(STR(?GML),"<gml:LineString xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml\"><gml:posList srsDimension=\"3\">","") AS ?gml)
    BIND(REPLACE(STR(?gml),"</gml:posList></gml:LineString>","")AS ?XYZ)
       
    }
    UNION
    { 
    ?uri rdf:type gwsw:Hemelwaterriool;
         gwsw:hasAspect ?ori.
    ?ori gwsw:hasAspect ?lijn.
    ?lijn gwsw:hasValue ?GML.
    BIND(REPLACE(STR(?GML),"<gml:LineString xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml\"><gml:posList srsDimension=\"3\">","") AS ?gml)
    BIND(REPLACE(STR(?gml),"</gml:posList></gml:LineString>","")AS ?XYZ)
       
    }
    UNION
    { 
    ?uri rdf:type gwsw:Vuilwaterriool;
         gwsw:hasAspect ?ori.
    ?ori gwsw:hasAspect ?lijn.
    ?lijn gwsw:hasValue ?GML.
    BIND(REPLACE(STR(?GML),"<gml:LineString xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml\"><gml:posList srsDimension=\"3\">","") AS ?gml)
    BIND(REPLACE(STR(?gml),"</gml:posList></gml:LineString>","")AS ?XYZ)
    }
    }''')

for gml in gmls:
    print(f"{gml.XYZ}")
```

Comment: can you please share the query in text format

Comment: I edited the post with the query in text format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a triple quote for constructing a multi-line string, the backslash-doublequote becomes simply a doublequote.

```py
'''
"<gml:LineString xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml\"><gml:posList srsDimension=\"3\">"
'''
```

becomes

```py
'''
"<gml:LineString xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><gml:posList srsDimension="3">"
'''
```

which is probably not what you want.

Try to rewrite it as

```py
'''
'<gml:LineString xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><gml:posList srsDimension="3">'
'''
```